# How to handle click event for preferences in android

Tags: android, android-preferences

```
 public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceClickListener{


private Preference mLoginPreference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_layout);

    mLoginPreference = getPreferenceManager().findPreference(
            getString(R.string.login_pref));
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

    if(preference.getKey().equals(getString(R.string.login_pref))) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, FacebookLoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

In settings_layout.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@android:color/white" >

<Preference
    android:key="@string/login_pref"
    android:title="@string/login_title" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I have an app which as settings screen, In this `Login to your Account` option is there which will login FB account of the user and summary will be updated.
Here is a code I written, but it is not working and also i want to update the summary of the `Login to your Account` whether user is logged in or not using FaceBook Account.
Any Help, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once login is done inside `FacebookLoginActivity` you can set the result code using  `setResult`(Result code) before finishing the activity and inside `SettingsActivity` override `onActivityResult`(Result code) and change the label that user is logged in.

Comment: very much thanks amit, it works now and also i didn't registered preference click listener